# RetrofitService not getting called/working and has no error either Android Retrofit, Kotlin, Viewmodel

Tags: android, api, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

Hi I am trying to make a basic api call using retrofit and put the objects on recyclerview. Below is the code for Retrofit Instance, service, viewmodel.

SearchFragmentViewModel.kt

```
class SearchFragmentViewModel(application: Application):       AndroidViewModel(application){

var eventSearchList: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<EventSearchData>>
//   var eventSearchList: MutableLiveData<EventSearchList>

val TAG:String = "demo"``


init {
    eventSearchList = MutableLiveData()
    //getDataFromApi("")
}

fun getRecyclerListDataObserver(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<EventSearchData>> {
    return eventSearchList
}

 fun getDataFromApi(tempString: String) {
     val TAG: String = "demo"
     
     viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val retroInstance = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance()
                                 .create(RetrofitService::class.java)
        val call = retroInstance.getEventDataFromApi(tempString) //from this point not working
             if (call.isExecuted){
                 Log.d(TAG, "if call is excecuted")
             }
             call.enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<EventSearchList>{
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<EventSearchList>, response: Response<EventSearchList>) {

                 Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: on success")
                 if (response.isSuccessful){
                     eventSearchList.postValue(response.body()?.event)
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ${response.body()}")
                 }else{
                     eventSearchList.postValue(null)
                 }
             }


             override fun onFailure(call: Call<EventSearchList>, t: Throwable) {
                 eventSearchList.postValue(null)
                 Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: call retrofit")                 }

         })
             Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: dfdag refdhdfhtrofit")
    }

 }
}
```

RetroInstance.kt

```
class RetrofitInstance {

companion object{
    val BASE_URL ="https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/"

    fun getRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
}
```

RetrofitService.kt

```
 interface RetrofitService {

 @GET("searchevents.php")
 suspend fun getEventDataFromApi(@Query("e") query: String):            Call<EventSearchList>
  }
```

From the call method in viewmodel, not getting anything,(at first I tried to display the response.body, but no success) eventually after debugging the code I fund that no LogCat is getting printed after than point. Please le me know what is it I am doing wrong.

P.S - tried checking android:textTraffic="true,
gradle files for retrofit2 library implementation,
with using callback and withoout callback, but nothing gets past the retroservice call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are trying to use two different threading tools together and that can not work. One is **coroutines** and the second is **enqueue**. If you want to use enqueue you don't have to suspend your GET fun  in your interface i.e it will look like this

```
interface RetrofitService {

@GET("searchevents.php") fun getEventDataFromApi(@Query("e") query: String): Call 
}
```

Also you will have to wrap your response class in the interface with Call like this

```
interface RetrofitService {

@GET("searchevents.php") suspend fun getEventDataFromApi(@Query("e") query: String): Call<EventSearchList> 
}
```

If **EventSearchList** is your expected response fromthe API.

Hence, don't need the coroutines scope in the ViewModel. your call will look like

```
 fun getDataFromApi(tempString: String) {
val call = retroInstance.getEventDataFromApi(tempString)
 call.enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<EventSearchList>{
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<EventSearchList>, response: Response<EventSearchList>) {

                 Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: on success")
                 if (response.isSuccessful){
                     eventSearchList.postValue(response.body()?.event)
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ${response.body()}")
                 }else{
                     eventSearchList.postValue(null)
                 }
             }


             override fun onFailure(call: Call<EventSearchList>, t: Throwable) {
                 eventSearchList.postValue(null)
                 Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: call retrofit")                 }

         })

 }
```

In addition, I don't know what your **retrofit2** means. I guess you will understand better.

I will also advise you add OKHTTP Interceptor https://blog.mindorks.com/okhttp-interceptor-making-the-most-of-it to your retrofit to know what is wrong with your network calls

```
class RetrofitInstance {

companion object{
    val BASE_URL ="https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/"

    fun getRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
             .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)).build())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

For coroutines, you may check this https://blog.mindorks.com/using-retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutines-in-android out and relate it with your work

Comment: Thanks @user11874398, you saved my day!!, it worked. I was thinking the the APImethod calls should be written as "suspend fun"

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Could you please mark the answer as accepted?  @nikhilsurya

Comment: I did @user11874398